# Cisco IP SLA monitor failure on tcpConnect but the host can be telneted from router

Tags: networking, router, failover, cisco

I want to configure a failover link to my cache server with Cisco policy routing.
So I attempted to create an ip sla monitor. here is the syntax in the cisco router (there is possibility of being wrong words in parameters but here I just wanted to show the styles):

```
R1(config)# ip sla monitor 1
          type tcpConnect destip 10.10.10.2 destport 1010
          timeOut 30
          frequency 30
R1(config)# ip sla monitor 1 schedule life forever starttime now
```

and then created a track watching for that monitor and use it on routing. But every time I check out the ip sla monitor 1 statistics like this it fails. While I can telnet the 10.10.10.2:1010 with router!

```
R1# sh ip sla monitor statistics 1

<some stuff here>

last operation return code: No connection
number of success: 0
number of failures: 66
```

and the track return me the link is down.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use control protocol.

```
type tcpConnect destip 10.10.10.2 destport 1010 control disable
```

> IP SLAs uses the control protocol to notify the IP SLAs Responder to enable the target port temporarily. This action allows the Responder to reply to the TCP Connect operation. In this example, because the target is not a router and a well-known TCP port is used, there is no need to send the control message.
>   http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_4/ip_sla/configuration/guide/hstcpc.html